# Multiple Token Authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can a user login in multiple devices because what we have is just a single Token Authentication on our django app. As an authenticated user when I login on Google Chrome it works fine but when I visit at the mozilla time and I logged out at the chrome the token that has been created has been deleted upon logout so when I login at mozilla, the token is already gone and we can not log-in on mozilla and throws a Forbidden response on the console.

Comment: I'm confused.. are you talking about authentication tokens or session cookies? DRF doesn't have "multiple" tokens for authentication, it has only one token per user, and cerrtanly  auth tokens are not destroyed on logout

Comment: Tokens,, can you provide an alternative for this one?

Answer (score 8):

It's been years since this question was asked, I worked around this issue with few lines of code, I hope someone will benefit from this.

DRF authentication relies on two things:

1. Token model (which is the source of this issue).
2. Authentication class.

I provided my own implementations of these two, and passed them to DRF.

```
# models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class MultiToken(Token):
user = models.ForeignKey(  # changed from OneToOne to ForeignKey
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tokens',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
)
```

Then I implemented an Authentication class, just to override the model.

```
# appname.authentication.py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

from appname.models import MultiToken


class MultiTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    model = MultiToken
```

Pass this Authentication class, to DRF.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'appname.authentication.MultiTokenAuthentication',
    ],
    ...
}
```

of course, Since I inherited from DRF Token model, I had to remove `rest_framework.authtoken` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I also, changed the ObtainAuthToken APIView to suit this new change.

```
class LoginApi(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = dict(request=request, view=self)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context=context)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        update_last_login(None, user, )
        token = MultiToken.objects.create(user=user)
        data = {'token': token.key}

        return Response(data)
```

HOPE THIS HELPS.

Answer (score 7):

You're question is a little convoluted, but I think you are getting at the problem referenced here:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/601

The official token authentication does not support (and unfortunately has no intention of supporting) multiple tokens, but you may be able to use django-rest-knox, available here: https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox

Edit: I previously recommended django-rest-multitoken, but django-rest-knox seems to be more actively maintained.