# Django REST Framework multi token per user

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to use Django REST Framework in my project, As you know by default DRF allow us to have just one token per a user but I have to allow users to login from some different devices and give them independent token for any device.

**Question**: how I can use multi token per a user in my project and manage them in admin panel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840734/multiple-token-authentication-in-django-rest-framework